# Regex and browser dependency

Tags: javascript

Why does the following regex:

```
var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9,-\s]/g
```

not work in Firefox and IE, but works in Safari and Chrome.

But if I change it to:

```
var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s,]/g
```

It works on all the above-mentioned browsers.

Can anybody please explain why the comma (`,`) is the bad guy here?

Comment: I am not 100% sure (hence the comment) but your issue might be the hyphen. Try changing your regex to `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s,-]/g`. Within square brackets the `-` denotes a range, which might be breaking your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested out this script and it worked on Internet Explorer(8), Chrome and Firefox: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s,-]/g`. The above up votes for my comment makes me believe I am right.

Comment: Yep. If the idea is to match an actual literal hyphen it is best to put the hyphen just before the `]` to avoid confusion with ranges - or escape it with a backslash...